# Um, I earned the Vox Populi badge but haven't voted at all in the last few days

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Does this mean my account has been hacked somehow? or is there something wrong with the system? As I understand it the Vox Populi badge gets awarded when you've used the maximum of 40 votes in a day.

... and now I see a bunch of other people just earned this badge so I suspect this is a bug. But still, it's a bit nervous-making. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but I just earned it both here *and* on Stack Overflow. Probably a hiccup in the system ...

Comment: Me, too. Phantom voting FTW!

Comment: I thought I actually did some voting in my sleep or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there is a bug with Vox Populi only that is awarding too many of them, beyond the expected more for retroactive awards, and a fix is being deployed now.  The erroneous awards there will be cleaned up shortly.

Comment: It's gone! Stinkin' badges. :-) thanks